# Velocity of a point in a massed spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring

I got a Doubt that what if the spring has mass
I found the following question

When one end of a spring (of mass m and length l ) is pulled with velocity V1 and other and with velocity V2 then velocity of a point on spring at a distance x from first end is given by formula
V1+ (x/l)×V2

I tried to prove this but I didn't get any idea
I tried to by putting x=0, x=l the equation satisfied for those...
My sir said that velocity varies linearly with distance x but I didn't understand why

Please help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elongation (or compression) of a spring distributes itself linearly over the spring's length.

That can easily be explained. Let's assume for a moment, the right half of the spring elongates more than the left half. Then the right half pulls stronger than the left half, thus pulling stronger on the middle point than the left half, until the middle point has moved to a location where both forces become equal because of equal elongation.

Generalizing that, every part of a spring gets the same relative elongation, spread equally over the length of the spring.

And as velocity is nothing else than the change of location (1st derivative, if you know that concept), this linear distribution also holds true for the velocities.

P.S.

The given formula (and my explanation) deliberately ignores the mass `m` of the spring.

If we start pulling on the spring's ends, some force is needed to accelerate the parts of the spring up to their final velocities, depending on the parts' masses, and this will create some quite complex dynamic behaviour with oscillations where the simple formula `V1+(x/l)×V2` no longer holds.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the formula is wrong. If you set x = L, then one end of the spring is moving at $v_1$ + $v_2$.  It should be $v_1$ + (x/L)($v_2 - v_1$).